# Basic SQl syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a basic query that changes a "post type" for any posts that contain the word "releases" in their post title.

The query I've written comes up with a syntax error, and I'm uncertain as to where I've gone wrong.

```
UPDATE TABLE wp_posts SET post_type = "release" WHERE post_title = "%RELEASE%";
```

Comment: In SQL double quotes are for delimited identifiers (e.g. "columnname"). Use single quotes for string literals. Also, do `LIKE '%RELEASE%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_type = 'release' 
WHERE post_title LIKE '%release%';
```

The syntax error comes from the additional "TABLE" keyword, which is not required.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'release' WHERE CHARINDEX('RELEASE', post_title) > 0
```

OR

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'release' WHERE post_title LIKE '%RELEASE%'
```

Comment: Give some explanation along with your answer, it will help the OP.

Comment: Thanks for contributing - Although I must admit I already tried the answer posted before yours. So as yet, this is untested by myself.

Comment: Sorry @Haris, I'm new at this :) . The first Update's condition is using CHARINDEX(text_to_find, column_to_search_in) and it returns int (the position where it finds the text_to_find in the text from column_to_search_in). The second Update uses LIKE (when I was writing it, Radu Gheorghiu already answered.

Comment: No problem @shanDB. You will probably get the chance to use CHARINDEX in other queries.